# How can i get raw SMTP content from draft on Gmail? (Gmail API)

Tags: node.js, google-api, smtp, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get raw SMTP content from draft on Gmail with Gmail API.

Gmail API returns just [users.drafts.Draft](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts#Draft) object. and gmail API no return raw SMTP content (`draft.message.raw`)

So, is any library or method that can change `Draft` object to SMTP raw content?

Comment: Have you tried doing a message.get and then checking whats in raw  [users.message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thx for answer me. but it returns undefined too

Comment: if you Add you code I will see what I can do 

Answer (score 0):

The following function shows how you can return the raw from a message.

```
/**
 * Gets the messages from the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {string} message Id.
 * @param {string} message message format (minimal, full, raw or metadata).
 */
async function getMessage(auth, id, format) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.get({
        userId: 'me',
        format: format,
        id: id
    });
    const raw = res.data.raw;
    if (!raw || raw.length === 0) {
        console.log('No raw message found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log(`raw - ${raw}`);
}
```

you can run it by using notice how the format needs to be set to raw.

```
await getMessage(auth, message.id, 'raw')
```